# Allowing Permissions for Rails on Bitnami Google Compute Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-compute-engine, permission-denied, bitnami

I am attempting to test the sample app provided by Bitnami in the Ruby Stack, I have placed the files in the `htdocs` folder:

[image]

and access the url `http://(IP)/sample`. The result is that the url is active but I do not have permission to access anything present as:

[image]

How can I alter the permissions for this sample app so I can access?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here. If you want to deploy your application using Passenger, you can follow the next guide.

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Ruby_Stack?highlight=ruby+stack#How_can_I_deploy_my_Rails_application.3f

Apart from that, if you want to deploy a new page using Apache, you have to give read privileges to Apache. You can run the following commands:

$ sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs

$ sudo chmod -R g+r /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs

I hope this helps.